# Data tables vs jQGrid vs Google Visualization performance wise

Tags: datatables, data-visualization, tablesorter, google-visualization

I need to display a large amount of data (around 50-60K rows). I was searching for javascript library which can accomplish this with following features:

- Pagination
- Sorting
- Grouping (optional)
- Aggregating (optional)
- Should work with Firefox and optionally with IE8+
- Should be open source or very cheap

All the data should be available in javascript, making calls to server for pagination is not an option.

I checked out [Data Table](http://datatables.net/), [jQGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), and [Google Visualization](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#table).

I have tried jQGrid in the past but found out that it is not a good fit for such large amount of data. So my question is can I use any of the other two libraries which can process such large amounts of data with given features? Or are there any other client-side libraries which can serve the purpose?

I have great inclination towards Google Visualization API since I would be able to draw charts as well with the same data. If anyone has tried Visualization with large datasets, can you please report its performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I'm not sure if this can really be considered an answer (nothing empirical here - more just my two cents from experience), I can confirm that I have completed a similar task using the Google vis api, though potentially slightly smaller data set - 30-50k rows.

- I used controls, filters and aggregations extensively, and will say that at that point things got a little hectic (60/70% CPU as far as Chrome Task manager was concerned, potentially ~1 second delay for certain aggregations). It was still usable however.
- At no point did I attempt to render all data points on a chart at once. In general, I think that using and aggregating 50/60k rows of data in the background will work (i.e. the js is capable of it), but trying to render *all* of those on multiple graph(s) will be problematic. If the visuals you present are a more concise aggregation of the data set then this should be ok.
- Admittedly I mostly tested for Chrome and FF. Gvis thankfully supports lots of browsers, but I personally did not have to consider them all during development.

Given your use case, I feel like the gvis DataTable object managed to handle the large data set and provide a lot of the useful functionality you'd like (grouping, aggregation etc). Whilst I'm not sure if I'd go this way again, I can also confirm that it did not break for me when I attempted to push it to the limits you described :)

Comment: >>Whilst I'm not sure if I'd go this way again<< Why not, do you have something better in mind?

Comment: In this case, I returned quite a large, nob-aggregated set of data from my server and did most of my aggregation work in the javascript. It worked, but were I to do this again I would probably try to push more of the aggregation work to the server (or possibly pre-aggregate) simply based on the speed/user experience issues I mentioned above.